# Take several msbs from int

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am trying to take the 11 msb bits and get their value like this:

```
value = lineIntData & 0xFFE00000 >> 21;
```

lineIntData is a number of 8 hexadecimal digits.

What I don't understand is why I get a compilation error saying `"Cannot Implicitly convert Long to Int"`. The error disappears if I either take one digit out of the hex mask (thus making it 7 digits) or if I change int from `int` to `long`.

Why do I even get this error? Isn't a single hex digit takes 4 bits, which means 8 digits is 32 bits so it should all fit a single Int32? If I'm doing it wrong, then how can I take the value of the 11 msbs of the number?

Comment: Try `unsigned int` instead of `int`

Comment: Jon Skeet is the expert here (*the* expert for C#), so his solution is most likely more correct than I could ever muster. And I wasn't sure about the cast in the first place, which is why wrote it in a comment instead of in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `0xFFE00000` is `uint` (because it's greater than `0x7fffffff`), and there's no `&(int, uint)` operator, so both sides are promoted to `long`.

The fix is simple: just shift and *then* mask:

```
value = (lineIntData >> 21) & 0x7ff;
```

Now everything stays an `int` throughout.

By the way, I personally *always* use brackets when shifting and masking. It means I don't need to remember the precedence rules for those operators. While I remember precedence for some operators, this is one case where I'd rather just use brackets.

Comment: @Jon Skeet what about the way I took the MSBs? couldn't I just make the shift without the bitwise and? since it just shift everything i need to the beginning and put all 0s for me?

Comment: @YonatanNir: Not if this is an `int` - if the top bit of the original value is set, the shift will fill with 1s instead of 0s. If you used `uint` to start with, you'd just need to shift.

Comment: it should be `(lineIntData >> 21) & 0x7FF;`

Comment: or `(lineIntData >> 21) & (1 << 11 - 1);`

Comment: @YonatanNir: Please note the correction here. That's what I get for answering in the middle of the night :)